# How can you target just one id in jquery local storage?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I've been trying to make a to-do list and so far have the add and delete working. I have to add a section to mark the item as finished so I got some code to work well the way I liked. I always try to work on a separate file when experimenting with code so when I got it to work I tried transferring it into the to-do file and now its not working. 
I figured out the reason why it won't work is because I haven't targeted the item id (the one generated when its input to the list)
I tried to do this the same way the delete targets the id:

```
function completeTodo() {

    var todo_item = $(this).parent();

    if (todo_item) {

        var id = parseInt( todo_item.attr('id').replace('item', '') );

        if (id) {
            if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
                if (localStorage.todos) {

                    var todo_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.todos);


                    if (localStorage.getItem("background") != null) {
                        getImage = localStorage.background;
                        $(".done").addClass(getImage);
                    }


                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.palette').click(function () {
                            getImage = localStorage.background;
                            $(".done").removeClass(getImage);
                            localStorage.removeItem('background');
                            var setImage = $(this).attr(id);
                            $(".done").addClass(setImage);
                            localStorage.setItem("background", setImage);
                        });
                    });


                    localStorage.todos = JSON.stringify(todo_list);


                    drawTodos();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This however didn't work and I can't figure out a way to do it. The 'section' tag that contains the '.done' class is generated with the id in the jquery aswell:

```
$.each(todo_list, function(id, todo) {
                todos = todos + '<section class="todo_item" id="item' + id + '"><span id="complete" class="palette complete">Complete</span><span id="incomplete" class="palette incomplete">Incomplete</span><span class="done">' + todo.name + '</span><a href="#" class="edit_todo"><img src="img/edit.png" alt="edit list item" /></a><a href="#" class="remove_todo"><img src="img/delete.png" alt="delete list item" /></a></section>';
            });
```

how can I target the id generated in the 'section' so that I can mark it as complete?

Answer (score 0):

First off, it looks like you're storing raw HTML in local storage. It would be better to store your data within an object (JSON, aka JavaScript Object Notation) if you want to manipulate it more.

```
todo_list = {
  1 : "item 1",
  2 : "item 2"
};
```

If you want to store raw HTML, then completely replace the raw html.